# Notation: set X whose elements are smaller than each elements of set Y

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, relations

Does there exist some notation to indicate that all elements of a set X are smaller than all elements of a set Y?

Comment: $\max X < \min Y$?

Comment: @angryavian that does not work if e.g. $X=(0,1)$ and $Y=\{1\}$.

Comment: @angryavian - Is there any guarantee that max (or sup) and min (or inf) exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can state:$$\forall x\in X\forall y\in Y[x<y]$$I cannot find a shortcut by means of suprema, infima, maxima or minima. So if that's what you are looking for then this does not answer your question.

Comment: Maybe also $y > \max X$ for all $y \in Y$?

Comment: But there are situations where $X$ *does not have a maximum*. E.g. if $X=(0,1)$. A maximum of $X$ is by definition an element of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y, x < y$